# Evernote API: related to Intent sample

Tags: android, evernote

I am making an application (on Android) and trying to combine my application with Evernote. for this i have download SDK and sample code. I prefer to use "Intent " way of calling Evernote through my Application. So the problem is when i call create note intenet the Evernote opens and note is save/uploaded in the Evenote application. After that i want following things, 
- how can i get New created Note tile to show in my application
-How can i get Note gguid back in my application to open specific note later.

there is mathod called in my application after return if the intent "onActivityResult" , im sure something to do in this mathod but not sure what to do. i called this method "data.getStringExtra("gguid");" in "onActivityResult" method but it dosent work

Could someone please help

Comment: What method you have used for calling create note intent.give the code in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because note GUIDs are created on the server side, and because synchronization with the server is asynchronous, there's no way to pass the new note's GUID back after the note creation activity completes. If, for example, the device is offline when the note is saved, the GUID will not be available until the device is connected and Evernote for Android successfully synchronizes.

Comment: Thanks alo seth, so what could be the solution? what shoudl i do know to get Guid of the Note. becouse when i creat some note later i wanted to update that note (or do something else with) i need Guid to later call it. lookign for your response

Comment: I would be interested in that too!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to directly communicate with the evernote servers using the api.